# How to make the width of a Listbox wider when using the MVC helper @Html.ListBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I am using the MVC helper:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(vm => vm.SelectedUsers, Model.UserSelectList, "--- All ---")
```

How can I make the listbox wider, currently the names are getting cut off.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the overloaded version of the method

```
Html.ListBoxFor(vm => vm.SelectedUsers, Model.UserSelectList, new { data-placeholder="-- All --", style = "width: 100%"});
```

etc. you can also give it CSS Classes and apply external styling.

Comment: but I have the default message in there also? "-- All --"

Comment: you can use, new { style = "width: 100%", data-placeholder="-- All --"}

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for your listbox in CSS:

```
.listBox
{
   width: 200px; //set your width or make it auto
}
```

Then set the class attribute:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(vm => vm.SelectedUsers, Model.UserSelectList,new { @class = "listBox" });
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the CSS files set the `max-width` for a select object to 260px. Try adjusting the `max-width`:

```
@Html.ListBox("CurrentValues", Model.UserSelectList, new { @class="form-control",@style="max-width:600px;width:100%;" });
```